# Saving settings for "AllowUserToOrderColumns" of my DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Is there a way to make my program remember the way columns are re-ordered so when the application is re-opened, it orders them the same way as it was when I closed the form. I can't find any properties for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a Windows Forms DataGridView, I'm not aware of any property that would do this for you automatically. I think you could devise a pretty simple scheme by handling the ColumnDisplayIndexChanged Event, though. Whenever the user changes the order of the columns, this event would be triggered, then you could save the column order in an XML file. When first creating the form with the DataGridView, you would need to read the data from the file and set the proper DisplayIndex for each column.

Hope that helps,

-Dan

Comment: Thanks Dan. Do you know where these column settings are kept?

Comment: You actually have to create the file with the column settings yourself. I was thinking maybe you could create a simple XML file that stores the DisplayIndex for each column. Something like this (sorry for the bad formatting):

<columns>
  <column Index="1" displayIndex="1" />
  <column Index="2" displayIndex="4" />
  <column Index="3" displayIndex="3" />
  <column Index="4" displayIndex="2" />
</columns>

Then you could just save this file in a Settings folder within your project and read/write to the file as needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
            var query = from DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns
                        orderby col.DisplayIndex
                        select col;

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in query)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(col.HeaderText);
                MessageBox.Show(col.DisplayIndex.ToString());
             }
```

Comment: when responding to older questions (especially 3 year old questions) you should try to provide some additional details regarding your solution. Please provide some explanation of your code, some reasons why your solution is different from the others given, or some explanation as to why your solution is more helpful than the others provided

Comment: You answer provides the properties used for determing the order but it doesn't answer the question on how to save and restore these settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write your own logic you can use the ability of a DataTable to read/write it's data or schema to a xml file.
If you close your form, just create a DataTable, add columns for each DataGridView in the right order and at startup just load this schema and set the order of the columns:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    // Save order
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("table");

        var query = from DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns
                    orderby col.DisplayIndex
                    select col;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in query)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(col.Name);
        }

        dt.WriteXmlSchema(@"c:\temp\columnorder.xml");
    }

    // Restore order
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.ReadXmlSchema(@"c:\temp\columnorder.xml");

        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[col.ColumnName].DisplayIndex = i;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer comes very late but maybe it will help someone in need.

What I found to work -- Very easy and saves as settings

I Made a new Class Library project to add to my solution and named it MySettingTypes.
I added the following class.

```
<Serializable()> Public Class DataGridViewColumnSetting
Property ColumnNames As List(Of String)
Property ColumnDisplayIndex As List(Of Integer)
Property ColumnVisiblility As List(Of Boolean)
Property ColumnSize As List(Of Integer)

Public Sub New()
    ColumnDisplayIndex = New List(Of Integer)
    ColumnNames = New List(Of String)
    ColumnSize = New List(Of Integer)
    ColumnVisiblility = New List(Of Boolean)
End Sub
```

End Class

Rebuild the MySettingTypes project
add it as a reference to your DatagridView Project.
In the window that houses your project you can add the fallowing code for saving and loading.

Go to your projects settings and add a new setting named YourDGVSettingsEntry.
When selecting the type, go to BROWSE and find DataGridViewColumnSetting under MySettingTypes.

```
 Private Sub loadSettings()
    If Not IsNothing(My.Settings.YourDGVSettingsEntry) Then
        Dim s As MySettingTypes.DataGridViewColumnSetting = My.Settings.YourDGVSettingsEntry
        Dim pos As Integer = 0
        For Each ColumnName As String In s.ColumnNames
            Try
                Me.YourDataGridView.Columns(ColumnName).DisplayIndex = s.ColumnDisplayIndex(pos)
                Me.YourDataGridView.Columns(ColumnName).Width = s.ColumnSize(pos)
                Me.YourDataGridView.Columns(ColumnName).Visible = s.ColumnVisiblility(pos)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            pos = pos + 1
        Next

    Else
        My.Settings.YourDGVSettingsEntry = New MySettingTypes.DataGridViewColumnSetting
        Me.saveSettings()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub saveSettings()
    Dim x As New MySettingTypes.DataGridViewColumnSetting
    For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In YourDataGridView.Columns
        x.ColumnNames.Add(c.Name)
        x.ColumnDisplayIndex.Add(c.DisplayIndex)
        x.ColumnSize.Add(c.Width)
        x.ColumnVisiblility.Add(c.Visible)
        My.Settings.YourDGVsettingsEntry = x
        My.Settings.Save()
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub yourDGVForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    'txtResultsCount.Text = "Saving settings"
    saveSettings()
End Sub

Private Sub yourDGVForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' myparent = Me.MdiParent
    loadSettings()
    'Setup()


End Sub
```

It's so easy and iv'e been importing these settings into my new releases. I'm about to add
the ability for the end user to custom name the column headers to whatever they desire.